# Search HTML5 localStorage values

Tags: javascript, html

I'm just wondering how to search for a specific value stored in local Storage.

I have tried to dispaly the search values using alert.

```
function search(){
   var sea = document.getElementById('searchbox').value;
   localStorage.getItem('sea',value);
   var value = $('#MyTable').find('tr#key_'+sea).children('td.two').text();
   alert(value); 
   }
```

But if i enter a value that is not stored in local storage,it is not showing null.

How do I display all the matching values from the local storage for the value i search?

Comment: `localStorage.getItem('sea',value);` should be held by a variable I guess..

Comment: but for all values its showing null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code logic should be as follows:

1. get the value from the search box, and store it in a variable
2. search in `localStorage` for a key with the name above
3. proceed to the DOM manipulation part

Code:

```
function search() {
  // Get the user's input from the page
  var searchQuery = document.getElementById('searchbox').value;

  // Get the item from LocalStorage
  var localStorageItem = localStorage.getItem(searchQuery);

  // Do your DOM manipulation magic
  var elementValue = $('#MyTable')
    .find('tr#key_' + localStorageItem)
    .children('td.two')
    .text();

  console.log(elementValue);
}
```

Note that there is a problem with the code above, for the times when the value does not exist in `LocalStorage`. Then, `localStorageItem` is going to be `null` and your DOM query, `.find('tr#key_' + localStorageItem)` will fail. 
You might want to wrap the DOM operation inside an if statement where you check if `localStorageItem !== null`.

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax for [`localStorage.getItem()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) is incorrect. The method takes only one parameter. The correct syntax is:

> var aValue = storage.getItem(keyName);

where `keyName` is a string containing the name of the key you want to retrieve the value of. The method returns the value of the key. So, you should store the returned value. If the key does not exist, null is returned.

I think your code should be

```
var sea = localStorage.getItem(value);
```

Comment: I want that same value to be displayed which i search for,users will be unaware of key.right?

Comment: @MaryAnn - End user will be unaware of the key. Provided you don't print it on the DOM. But if the end user has some JS knowledge he/she will be able to fetch the "key".

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve data from `localStorage` by specifying a key you are searching. you syntax is wrong.
the correct way is:

```
LocalStorage.getItem(*key*)
```

what you are using is the `.setItem()` syntax
which is:

```
LocalStorage.setItem(*key*, *value*)
```

Comment: Right..but if i try with a value not in local storage,its not displaying null.